# TinyMCE plugin filepicker replacement?

Tags: tinymce

Moving some TinyMCE plugins from 4 to 5.  Been digging through the docs on line, which have certainly helped.  Have found one thing I cannot resolve.

Have a plugin that chooses a file on the host server (not the client where the browser is running).  Original source uses:

type: 'filepicker',

But that is giving me an error:

```
The chosen schema: "filepicker" did not exist in branches: {
  "alertbanner": {},
  "bar": {},
  "button": {},
  "checkbox": {},
  "colorinput": {},
  "colorpicker": {},
  "dropzone": {},
  "grid": {},
  "iframe": {},
  "input": {},
  "selectbox": {},
  "sizeinput": {},
  "textarea": {},
  "urlinput": {},
  "customeditor": {},
  "htmlpanel": {},
  "imagetools": {},
  "collection": {},
  "label": {},
  "table": {},
  "panel": {}
```

}

None of which seem like they are a replacement for filepicker. Am I missing something ?

TIA

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug through the image plugin.  urlinput is the correct answer:

```
{type: 'urlinput',
name: 'filePath',
label: 'Document',
filetype: 'file',
value: filePath
```

Comment: This view doesn't include a button for selecting a file though. It's just a URL input text box.